# How to detect region of least energy in an Image

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing

I want to programmatically place text on an image in an area where there is least "going on".  It has been some time since I took Computer-Vision, could someone point me in the right direction.  Either with respect to C# or Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest dividing the image into distinct regions, each the size of the space you need for the text overlay.  Calculate some measure of visual "energy", such as standard deviation, and choose the region with the lowest value.  You could also slide a window around, looking for an arbitrary space of low energy, but this would be computationally much more expensive.

Comment: Exactly that I was thinking. Also was thinking... How would I thread it to speed up the "sliding"  :p

Comment: I imagine that it's not necessary to find the best window to the pixel level.  If just scanning a grid of distinct windows does not work, I'd try two interleaved grids before going to pixel-by-pixel scanning.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the image processing toolbox for Matlab, you can run an entropy filter ([ENTROPYFILT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/entropyfilt.html)) on the image, matching the filter size to the size of your text. Then, all you need to do is find the filter-result with the smallest value, and you have the center of where you want to put the text.

Comment: Do you know where I could find documentation on what EntropyFilt is doing in the background?

Comment: @maxfridbe: In the help it references `Gonzalez, R.C., R.E. Woods, S.L. Eddins, "Digital Image Processing using MATLAB", Chapter 11.`. Also, I would assume that it uses the same basic idea as `entropy`, which calculates the entropy on the entire image. Type `edit entropy` to see the code.